# JPA entity mapping to optional SecondaryTable

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have an entity.  I would like to optionally load additional information about the entity from a secondary table.  I have the following mapping.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "program", schema = "myschema" )
@SecondaryTable( name = "program_info", schema = "myschema", pkJoinColumns =
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn( name = "program_id", referencedColumnName = "program_id" ) )
public class Program { ... }
```

I have all the columns mapped appropriately, and a unit test that works.  The trouble comes when I have a row in the program table that does not have a corresponding row in the program_info table.  In that case it won't load the program at all.  I need to be able to mark the entire secondary table as optional.  I would prefer to stay away from having to create another entity/dao/service and do a 1-1 mapping.

I'm using eclipselink but would like to stay away from provider specific details if I can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I need to be able to mark the entire secondary table as optional.

EclipseLink will perform an `INNER JOIN` with a `SecondaryTable` so if there is no corresponding row in the secondary table, you'll get nothing. In other words EL expects to find a row in the secondary table (when creating, reading, updating, deleting).

If what you want is an `OUTER JOIN`, you should use an optional `OneToOne` association (maybe with a shared primary key in your case).

An alternative would be to use a database view (doing an `OUTER JOIN`) and to map the view.

> I would prefer to stay away from having to create another entity/dao/service and do a 1-1 mapping.

I don't see why having an optional `OneToOne` forces you to have a corresponding DAO and service. Manage the optional part through the main "holder" part.

#### See also

- JPA Wiki book

  - [Multiple table outer joins](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_table_outer_joins)

Comment: I can see what you are saying on the OneToOne, and I guess if I cascade that relationship I wouldn't need the dao and service.  As usual, a good answer from you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TopLink, EclipseLink: **If the database supports usage** of **outer join** syntax  in the where clause (Oracle, Sybase, SQL Server), then the multiple table **join expression could be used to configure an outer join** to be used to read the table.

There is my customizer for **Eclipselink** multiple table entity on oracle database

```
public class OuterJoinCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

  public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
    Map<DatabaseTable, Map<DatabaseField, DatabaseField>> tables =
        descriptor.getAdditionalTablePrimaryKeyFields();

      ExpressionBuilder builder = new ExpressionBuilder();
      Expression expression = null;

      for (Map.Entry<DatabaseTable, Map<DatabaseField, DatabaseField>> table :
          descriptor.getAdditionalTablePrimaryKeyFields().entrySet()) {
        Expression criteria = null;

        for (Map.Entry<DatabaseField, DatabaseField> fields : table.getValue().entrySet()) {
              // NOTE: equalOuterJoin (+)= SUPPORTED BY ORACLE!
              Expression fieldExp =
              builder.getField(fields.getValue()).equalOuterJoin(builder.getField(fields.getKey()));
          criteria = (criteria == null) ? fieldExp : criteria.and(fieldExp);
        }

        if (criteria != null)
          expression = (expression == null) ? criteria : expression.and(criteria);
      }

      if (expression != null)
        descriptor.getQueryManager().setMultipleTableJoinExpression(expression);
    }

  }
}
```

In Hibernate it is mush easier

```
@Table(optional = true)
```