# Entity with column from a SecondaryTable isn't returned if row in other table doesn't exist

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have two tables, a Entity table and a table containing some data (also from other systems, not managed by JPA)

The entity table is like

```
ID ; Name  ; Ref
-----------------
1  ; Test1 ; D1
2  ; Test2 ; D2
3  ; Test3 ; D3
```

The data table is like

```
EID ; Value
-------------
D1  ; Data1
D2  ; Data2
```

In my Entity I have defined

```
@SecondaryTable(name = "data", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "EID", referencedColumnName = "Ref"))
```

...

```
@Column(table = "data", name = "EID", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = true)
private String _external_data;
```

I'm fetching the Entities using NamedQueries. As long as I fetch Test1 or Test2 (IDs: 1,2) they are returned. Fetching Test3 (ID 3) doesn't work, as the external data table has no entries matching the Ref.

Is there any solution to also return entities with no mathing rows in the Data-table?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard JPA way to accomplish this. JPA providers probably support it, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53103819/2764255) may help.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos this helped. Using a OneToOne relation did the trick and wasn't more effort than using the SecondaryTable annotation